# complex integral with non integer power

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to calculate this integral

$$I\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{exp(-\mathrm{i}\mathbf{q}\mathbf{r}})}{-\mathrm{i}\omega+\mathbf{q}^{3-\eta}(-\mathrm{i}\omega)^{\eta/3}} \, \mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{q}$$
   where $q$ and $\omega$ are complex variables, while $\eta$ is a real such that $1<\eta <2$. 
After a change of variable it is possible to show that (if I made any mistake) $I$ is equal to
$$I=\frac{4\pi}{r}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{q \sin(qr)}{-\mathrm{i}\omega+q^{3-\eta}(-\mathrm{i}\omega)^{\eta/3}}\,\mathrm{d}q$$ At this stage I don't know how to calculate this integral. I would want to apply Residue theorem  but I don't know how to do because of the non-integer power in the denominator ($\eta$). I know that there is a branch cut but that's all.

Does any body have an idea? Even if it is not exactly this integral I am interested in any suggestion about this kind of integral with non integral powers at the denominator.

Comment: The setup of this problem worries me.  You have what appears to be an integral over a 3D region, yet you are showing the integral over the 1D real line.   (I assume you mean all of 3D space.)  Then, it is not clear what precisely you mean by a vector raised to a non-integer power.  How did you make this substitution?

Comment: @RonGordon in the first integral I mean triple integral over all the 3d space. Replacing $\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{q}$ by $q^2\cos\theta\cos \phi$ and integrating over $\phi$ and $\theta$ I obtained the second equation. It is possible that I made a mistake doing this change of variable.